# How to create a folder and a file on Google Drive using API? Android

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I would like to create a folder and a file in Google Drive using Google Drive API in my Android app.
I read the document and just give this code:

```
    File fileMetadata = new File();
    fileMetadata.setName("Invoices");
    fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.folder");

    File file = driveService.files().create(fileMetadata)
            .setFields("id")
            .execute();
    System.out.println("Folder ID: " + file.getId());
```

But the editor always wants me to create a local variable of `driveService`.
what is `driveService`?  the quickstart document seems not a example for android?

Answer (score 2):

Drive Android API is deprecated since December 2018, and you should use the [REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk), which contains [this quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java).

In this case, the `driveService` corresponds to an instance of [Class Drive](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.html), and can be used to call the API through the Java library.

Instantiating `Drive` requires you to provide `credentials`. You can see a detailed example in the referenced Java quickstart (where `driveService` is instead named `service`), and can see the different ways of doing this, documented in the [library docs](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-drive/latest/index.html): see [Drive constructor](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.html#Drive-com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport-com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory-com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer-) and [Drive.Builder](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/Drive.Builder.html).

#### Reference:

- [Google Drive Android API Deprecation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation)
- [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk)
- [Java Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java)
- [Drive API Javadoc documentation](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-services-drive/latest/index.html)